# How can I manually construct a params hash key whose value equals to another hash with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am playing around with the `$.ajax();` function and I am trying to construct a specific param key for my rails controller to process.

The param that I am trying to generate should look like this:

```
{ stack_entry: { project_name: 'project_name } }
```

I've been playing around with the data field for the ajax action but I can't construct the url just right. Here are some examples:

```
 data: "stack_entry=" + "?project_name=" + $projectUrlName,
 data: "stack_entry=" + "&project_name=" + $projectUrlName,
 data: "stack_entry=" + "project_name=" + $projectUrlName,
```

These implementations generate these types of params values:

```
{ stack_entry: "",
  project_name: "project_name }

{ stack_entry: "project_name=project_name" }
```

etc. etc.

How can I get the stack_entry key to be another hash value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "name" attribute should be `"stack_entry[project_name]"`, so it would be

```
data: {"stack_entry[project_name]": $projectUrlName}
```

as an object in JS, or if you want to do it as a string,

```
data: "stack_entry[project_name]="+$projectUrlName
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could actually write it directly like that.

Comment: With param structures, "[]" means "an array" and "[foo]" means "make a hash with a key called foo".  You can combine these as much as you want.